# Python Scrape NBA Tracking Drives Data

Tags: python, web-scraping, get, google-chrome-devtools

I am fairly new to Python. I am trying to scrape NBA Drives data via https://stats.nba.com/players/drives/

I used Chrome Devtools to find the API URL. I then used the requests package to get the JSON string.

**Original code:**

```
import requests
headers = {"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0..."}
url = " https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=PerGame&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=Drives&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight="
r = requests.get(url, headers = headers)
d = r.json()
```

This no longer works, however. For some reason the request for the URL link below times out on the NBA server. So I need to find a new way to get this information.

< https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=PerGame&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=Drives&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight=>

I was exploring  Chrome devtools and I found out that the desired JSON string was stored in the Network XHR Response tab.  Is there any way to scrape that into python. See the image below.

[Chrome Devtools: XHR Response JSON string](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imWfE.png)

Comment: `Network XHR Response tab` shows results from requests send from browser to server - they don't keep it and you can't get it. Better use real header `User-Agent` and other headers used by web browser. It is good also use `requests.Session` to keep all cookies used by server. It may need to use `requests.get()` for main pge to get cookies from server.

Answer (score 2):

I tested url with other headers (which I saw in `DevTool` for this request) and it seems it needs header `Referer` to work correctly

**EDIT 2020.08.15:**

I had to add new headers to read it

```
'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
```

---

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/players/drives/',
    #'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',

    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats?College=&Conference=&Country=&DateFrom=&DateTo=&Division=&DraftPick=&DraftYear=&GameScope=&Height=&LastNGames=0&LeagueID=00&Location=&Month=0&OpponentTeamID=0&Outcome=&PORound=0&PerMode=PerGame&PlayerExperience=&PlayerOrTeam=Player&PlayerPosition=&PtMeasureType=Drives&Season=2019-20&SeasonSegment=&SeasonType=Regular+Season&StarterBench=&TeamID=0&VsConference=&VsDivision=&Weight='
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

---

**BTW:** the same but with params as dictionary so it is easier to set different value

```
import requests

headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0',
    #'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:72.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/72.0',
    'Referer': 'https://stats.nba.com/players/drives/',
    #'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',

    'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats',
    'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',
}

url = 'https://stats.nba.com/stats/leaguedashptstats'

params = {
    'College': '',
    'Conference': '',
    'Country': '',
    'DateFrom': '',
    'DateTo': '',
    'Division': '',
    'DraftPick': '',
    'DraftYear': '',
    'GameScope': '',
    'Height': '',
    'LastNGames': '0',
    'LeagueID': '00',
    'Location': '',
    'Month': '0',
    'OpponentTeamID': '0',
    'Outcome': '',
    'PORound': '0',
    'PerMode': 'PerGame',
    'PlayerExperience': '',
    'PlayerOrTeam': 'Player',
    'PlayerPosition': '',
    'PtMeasureType': 'Drives',
    'Season': '2019-20',
    'SeasonSegment': '',
    'SeasonType': 'Regular Season',
    'StarterBench': '',
    'TeamID': '0',
    'VsConference': '',
    'VsDivision': '',
    'Weight': '',
}

r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params)
#print(r.request.url)
data = r.json()

print(data)
```

Comment: I tried this but had no luck. I still can't get a response from the API even using this exact code

Comment: @JSONK. first you should display `r.text` to see what you get from server. Maybe you get warning for bots and spamers. This question is almost 1 year old and web page could change all links or add new method to get data.

Comment: @JSONK - I checked code and web page and I had to add headers `'x-nba-stats-origin': 'stats', 'x-nba-stats-token': 'true',` to work again.

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked and I've been able to get a lot of work done on my project. I appreciate the help